# How to set up an inequality to check for a "consumption" (basically collision)

Tags: python, pygame, inequality

I am trying to make a snake game in python with pygame... the one that moves around and eats the food. But I can't seem to get the cookie to move whenever the "snake" travels over it.

I tried setting up an inequality to compare the position of the food and the position of the snake but its not working...

```
import pygame, sys, random, time
screenWidth = 500
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth,screenWidth))
#this begins the game
pygame.init()
#This sets a caption
pygame.display.set_caption("Picnic")

#Variables:
snakeFace = pygame.image.load('morrison.png')
x= 50
y= 50
snakewidth = 30
snakeheight = 30
food1width = 40
food1height = 17
food2width = 25
food2height = 26
food3width = 27
food3height = 23
vel = 5
run = True
lastKey = None
food1 = pygame.image.load("thinMint.png")
food2 = pygame.image.load("cookie.png")
food3 = pygame.image.load("triscuit.png")
randFoodX1 = 0
randFoodY1 = 0
randFoodX2 = 0
randFoodY2 = 0
#randFoodX1 = random.randrange(1, 50, 1) * 10
#randFoodY1 = random.randrange(1, 50, 1) * 10

def generateFoodPosition():
    randFoodX1 = random.randrange(1, 40, 1) * 10
    randFoodY1 = random.randrange(1, 40, 1) * 10
    randFoodX2 = random.randrange(1, 40, 1) * 10
    randFoodY2 = random.randrange(1, 40, 1) * 10
    randFoodX3 = random.randrange(1, 40, 1) * 10
    randFoodY3 = random.randrange(1, 40, 1) * 10
    if randFoodX1 == randFoodX2 or randFoodY1 == randFoodY2 or 
        randFoodY2==randFoodY3 or randFoodY1== randFoodY3 or 
        randFoodX2 == randFoodX3 or randFoodX3 == randFoodX1:
        generateFoodPosition()
    else:
        return [randFoodX1, randFoodY1, randFoodX2, 
                randFoodY2, randFoodX3, randFoodY3]
foodPositions = generateFoodPosition()

def checkForConsumption():
    if ((x + snakewidth) < (foodPositions[0] + food2width + 5 
  and (x + snakewidth) > (foodPositions[0] + food2width - 5)))  or 
((y + snakeheight) < (foodPositions[1] + food2height + 5 and (x + 
snakeheight) > (foodPositions[1] + food2height - 5))):
        foodPositions[0] = random.randrange(1, 40, 1) * 10
    foodPositions[1] = random.randrange(1, 40, 1) * 10
    if ((x + snakewidth) < (foodPositions[2] + food2width + 5 and (x 
+ snakewidth) > (foodPositions[2] + food2width - 5)))  or ((y + 
 snakeheight) < (foodPositions[3] + food2height + 5 and (x + 
 snakeheight) > (foodPositions[3] + food2height - 5))):
    foodPositions[2] = random.randrange(1, 40, 1) * 10
    foodPositions[3] = random.randrange(1, 40, 1) * 10
if ((x + snakewidth) < (foodPositions[4] + food2width + 5 and (x + 
 snakewidth) > (foodPositions[4] + food2width - 5)))  or ((y + 
snakeheight) < (foodPositions[5] + food2height + 5 and (x + 
 snakeheight) > (foodPositions[5] + food2height - 5))):
    foodPositions[4] = random.randrange(1, 40, 1) * 10
    foodPositions[5] = random.randrange(1, 40, 1) * 10

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(10) #1/2 milisecond delay
     #this controls the "X" button
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            lastKey = event.key

#this controls the movement of the snake
if lastKey == pygame.K_LEFT and x > vel:
    x-=vel
if lastKey == pygame.K_RIGHT and x< screenWidth - snakewidth - vel:
    x+=vel
if lastKey == pygame.K_DOWN and y < screenWidth - snakeheight - vel:
    y+= vel
if lastKey == pygame.K_UP and y > vel:
    y-=vel

#if x == (foodPositions[0] or foodPositions[2] or foodPositions[4]) or y== (foodPositions[1] or foodPositions[3] or foodPositions[5]):
checkForConsumption()
gameDisplay.fill((0,0,0))
gameDisplay.blit(snakeFace,(x, y))
gameDisplay.blit(food1, (foodPositions[0], foodPositions[1]))
gameDisplay.blit(food2, (foodPositions[2], foodPositions[3]))
gameDisplay.blit(food3, (foodPositions[4], foodPositions[5]))
pygame.display.update()
print(x)
print(y)


pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth,screenWidth))
pygame.quit()
```

Again, I expected that when the snake moved over the cookie for it to move to a different spot

Comment: Using PyGame `rect` would save you heaps of work. https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect . The whole `checkForConsumption()` would be 3-4 short lines.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, Pygame has a method for [detecting collision between rectangles](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect).  Fortunately for you, the blit method [returns a Rect object](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit).  This means that, when you draw the snake face and food images onto the screen, you can hold on to these return values and use them to detect collisions between the snake and the food.

Here is a short snippet to illustrate what I'm talking about.

You can change the drawing code in your main loop to this:

```
gameDisplay.fill((0,0,0))
snakeRect = gameDisplay.blit(snakeFace,(x, y))
food1Rect = gameDisplay.blit(food1, (foodPositions[0], foodPositions[1]))
food2Rect = gameDisplay.blit(food2, (foodPositions[2], foodPositions[3]))
food3Rect = gameDisplay.blit(food3, (foodPositions[4], foodPositions[5]))
checkForConsumption()  # Note: It is important that you check for consumption after the food and snake have been drawn, as drawing updates their rectangles
pygame.display.update()
```

Then, your `checkForConsumption` method becomes much more simple:

```
def checkForConsumption():
    if snakeRect.coliderect(food1Rect):
        # Recalculate the new position of the food just as you did
        foodPositions[0] = random.randrange(1, 40, 1) * 10
        foodPositions[1] = random.randrange(1, 40, 1) * 10

        # Additionally, redraw the food at its new location
        gameDisplay.blit(food1, (foodPositions[0], foodPositions[1]))

    # Check each of the other pieces of food just as you did the first
```

This method allows you to take advantage of the methods built in to Pygame, that way you don't have to get lost in the implementation details of a collision detection method, while still using custom images for the snake head and food.  Although it is possible, and not too hard, to write your own collision detection method, this way is much more clean and uses the tools Pygame has provided.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in my project :

```
def collision_check(enemy_list, player_pos):
for enemy_pos in enemy_list:
    if detect_collision(enemy_pos, player_pos):
        return True
return False

def detect_collision(player_pos, enemy_pos):
p_x = player_pos[0]
p_y = player_pos[1]

e_x = enemy_pos[0]
e_y = enemy_pos[1]

if (e_x >= p_x and e_x < (p_x + player_size)) or (p_x >= e_x and p_x < (e_x + enemy_size)):
    if (e_y >= p_y and e_y < (p_y + player_size)) or (p_y >= e_y and p_y < (e_y + enemy_size)):
        return True
return False
```

Comment: and after collision i used :  screen.blit(label, (WIDTH - 200, HEIGHT - 40))